# Nest.js - Request hangs out only on first try

Tags: amazon-web-services, request, nestjs

we have a react.js app connected to our backend that uses nest.js.
We have an specific route that's been giving us a lot of trouble.
This route generates a pdf with all registries compiled in the ivd entity, and we have also a route that generate a pdf for a specific ivd registry (this one gave us some trouble in the past, but now it works really fine).

The problem as described in the title, happens only when we first click to generate the pdf for this route, the request keeps going on and then returns a 504 gateway hangout. At first we thought that the problem is the quantity of registries, but testing with the same database on a local and homologation server the request goes just fine. The problem happens only in the production server (aws hosted).

This production server is even more powerful than the homologation one and still gives us this problem. We compared pm2, nginx and system settings between both servers and they are pratically identical (except the database).

If we try a second time the request goes just fine, without any hassles.

Below are some codes we use.

**Single IVD**

**Controller**

```
@UseInterceptors(CrudRequestInterceptor)
  @Get('/pdf/:id')
  async getMetricsPDF(@Param('id') id: number) {
    try {
      return await this.service.generatePDF(id)
    } catch (err) {
      await ErrorService.next(err)
    }
  }
```

**Service**

```
async generatePDF(ivdMetricsId: number) {
    const qr = getConnection().createQueryRunner()
    await qr.connect()

    const ivdMetrics = await qr.manager.getRepository(IvdMetrics).findOne({
      where: { id: ivdMetricsId },
      relations: [
        'stepId',
        'destinyPlantingId',
        'plantingClassifiedId',
        'plantingClassifiedId.classId',
        'plantingClassifiedId.unityId',
        'originPlantingId',
        'lotId',
        'lotId.productId',
        'lotId.plannings',
        'lotId.plannings.stepId',
        'companyId',
        'classId',
      ],
    })

    const finalFile = await this.pdfService
      .toBuffer('ivdMetric-pdf', {
        locals: {
          ivdMetrics: await this.formatedIvdPDF(ivdMetricsId, ivdMetrics, true),
        },
      })
      .toPromise()

    const release = moment(ivdMetrics?.measurementDate)
      .tz('America/Sao_Paulo')
      .format('DD/MM/YY')

    let fileName = `relatorio_IVD_${release}.pdf`

    const fileToUpload: Express.Multer.File = {
      fieldname: 'Relatorio-IVD',
      originalname: fileName,
      encoding: 'application/pdf',
      mimetype: 'application/octet-stream',
      size: finalFile.length,
      buffer: finalFile,
      stream: null,
      filename: fileName,
      destination: '',
      path: '',
    }

    const uploaded = await this.awsService.uploadToPath(
      FOLDER.PDF_IVD_METRICS,
      fileToUpload,
      100,
      true
    )

    await qr.release()

    return uploaded
  }
```

**Full List of IVDs**

**Controller**

```
@Get('/indicator-pdf/:lot/:origin/:destiny/:classified')
  async getMetricsIndicatorPDF(
    @Param('lot') lot: number,
    @Param('origin') origin: number,
    @Param('destiny') destiny: number,
    @Param('classified') classified: number,
    @Req() request: CrudRequest
  ) {
    try {
      return await this.service.generateIndicatorPDF(
        lot,
        origin,
        destiny,
        classified,
        request
      )
    } catch (err) {
      await ErrorService.next(err)
    }
  }
```

**Service**

```
async generateIndicatorPDF(
    lot: number,
    origin: number,
    destiny: number,
    classified: number,
    req?: CrudRequest
  ) {
    const qr = getConnection().createQueryRunner()
    await qr.connect()

    const ivdMetrics = await qr.manager.getRepository(IvdMetrics).find({
      where: {
        lotId: lot,
        plantingClassifiedId: classified,
        originPlantingId: origin,
        destinyPlantingId: destiny,
        exclude: false,
      },
      relations: [
        'stepId',
        'destinyPlantingId',
        'plantingClassifiedId',
        'plantingClassifiedId.classId',
        'plantingClassifiedId.unityId',
        'originPlantingId',
        'lotId',
        'lotId.productId',
        'lotId.plannings',
        'lotId.plannings.stepId',
        'companyId',
        'classId',
      ],
    })

    const items = []

    for (const ivd of ivdMetrics) {
      const temp = await this.formatedIvdPDF(ivd.id, ivd, false)
      items.push(temp)
    }

    const info = {
      lot: ivdMetrics[0]?.lotId?.description.toUpperCase(),
      classified:
        `${ivdMetrics[0]?.plantingClassifiedId?.classId?.description} /
            ${ivdMetrics[0]?.plantingClassifiedId?.unityId?.description}
            ${ivdMetrics[0]?.plantingClassifiedId?.quantity}` ||
        'Não informado',
      variety: ivdMetrics[0]?.lotId?.variety || 'Não informado',
      generation: ivdMetrics[0]?.lotId?.generation || 'Não informado',
      origin:
        `${ivdMetrics[0]?.originPlantingId?.description.toUpperCase()}:
        ${moment(ivdMetrics[0]?.originPlantingId?.plantingDate)
          .tz('America/Sao_Paulo')
          .format('DD/MM/YY')}
        - ${moment(ivdMetrics[0]?.originPlantingId?.harvestDate)
          .tz('America/Sao_Paulo')
          .format('DD/MM/YY')}` || 'Não informado',
      destiny:
        `${ivdMetrics[0]?.destinyPlantingId?.description.toUpperCase()}:
         ${moment(ivdMetrics[0]?.destinyPlantingId?.plantingDate)
          .tz('America/Sao_Paulo')
          .format('DD/MM/YY')}
         - ${moment(ivdMetrics[0]?.destinyPlantingId?.harvestDate)
          .tz('America/Sao_Paulo')
          .format('DD/MM/YY')}` || 'Não informado',
      product:
        ivdMetrics[0]?.lotId?.productId?.description.toUpperCase() ||
        'Não informado',
      infoDestiny: items[0]?.infoPlantingDestiny,
      plannings: items[0]?.planningSteps,
      release: items[0]?.releaseDate,
    }

    const finalFile = await this.pdfService
      .toBuffer('ivdIndicator-pdf', {
        locals: {
          ivdIndicator: items,
          ivd: info,
        },
      })
      .toPromise()

    let fileName = `relatorio_indicador_IVD_${moment()
      .tz('America/Sao_Paulo')
      .format('DD/MM/YY')}.pdf`

    const fileToUpload: Express.Multer.File = {
      fieldname: 'Relatorio-indicador-IVD',
      originalname: fileName,
      encoding: 'application/pdf',
      mimetype: 'application/octet-stream',
      size: finalFile.length,
      buffer: finalFile,
      stream: null,
      filename: fileName,
      destination: '',
      path: '',
    }

    const uploaded = await this.awsService.uploadToPath(
      FOLDER.PDF_IVD_METRICS_INDICATOR,
      fileToUpload,
      100,
      true
    )

    await qr.release()

    return uploaded
  }
```

**Formatted IVD - A function that formats the fields to generate the pdf, common to both functions**

```
async formatedIvdPDF(
    ivdMetricsId: number,
    ivdMetrics: IvdMetrics,
    isSingle?: boolean
  ) {
    const qr = this.connection.createQueryRunner()
    await qr.connect()

    const ivdMetricsItems = await qr.manager.query(`
        select imi.db_bud_size as bud_size, imi.db_clove_size as clove_size,
        imi.dt_create_date as created_at, imi.bn_exclude as exclude,
        imi.ivd_metrics_sample_id as id, imi.bn_inner_bulb as inner_bulb,
        imi.db_ivd as ivd, imi.bn_status as status, imi.db_variation as variation
        from ivd_metrics_items imi join ivd_metrics im on imi.ivd_metrics_id = im.sample_Id
        where imi.ivd_metrics_id = ${ivdMetricsId} and imi.bn_exclude = false
    `)

    if (ivdMetricsItems?.length) {
      ivdMetricsItems.forEach(item => {
        item['budSize'] = item['bud_size']
        item['cloveSize'] = item['clove_size']
        item['createdAt'] = item['created_at']
        item['innerBulb'] = item['inner_bulb']
        delete item['bud_size']
        delete item['clove_size']
        delete item['created_at']
        delete item['inner_bulb']
      })
    }

    /* const ivdMetricsItems = await qr.manager
      .getRepository(IvdMetricsItem)
      .find({
        where: { ivdMetricsId: ivdMetricsId },
        select: [
          'budSize',
          'cloveSize',
          'createdAt',
          'exclude',
          'id',
          'innerBulb',
          'ivd',
          'status',
          'variation',
        ],
      }) */

    const rastreability = await qr.manager
      .getRepository(Rastreability)
      .findOne({
        where: {
          lotId: ivdMetrics?.lotId?.id || ivdMetrics?.lotId,
          exclude: false,
          startDate: LessThanOrEqual(ivdMetrics?.measurementDate),
        },
        order: {
          id: 'DESC',
        },
        select: ['id', 'startDate', 'endDate'],
      })

    const deviationValue = () => {
      let list: Array<number> = []
      ivdMetricsItems.forEach(item => {
        if (item?.ivd) list.push(item?.ivd)
      })
      const media = list.reduce(
        (total, value) => total + value / list.length,
        0
      )
      const deviation = list.reduce(
        (total, value) => total + (media - value) ** 2 / list.length,
        0
      )
      const deviationValue = Math.sqrt(deviation)
      return parseFloat(deviationValue.toFixed(2))
    }

    const deviationVariationValue = () => {
      const list: Array<number> = []
      ivdMetricsItems.forEach(item => {
        if (item?.variation) list.push(item?.variation)
      })
      const media = list.reduce(
        (total, value) => total + value / list.length,
        0
      )
      const deviation = list.reduce(
        (total, value) => total + (media - value) ** 2 / list.length,
        0
      )
      const deviationValue = Math.sqrt(deviation)
      return parseFloat(deviationValue.toFixed(2))
    }

    const higherAverages = () => {
      let avarage = 0
      const list: Array<any> = []
      const temp = ivdMetricsItems
      temp &&
        temp
          ?.sort((a, b) => b?.ivd - a?.ivd)
          .forEach((item, i) => {
            if (i <= 4) {
              list.push(item?.ivd?.toFixed(2))
              avarage += item?.ivd
            }
          })
      const avarageValue = avarage / list?.length
      return {
        list: list,
        avarage: parseFloat(avarageValue.toFixed(2)),
      }
    }

    const minorsAverages = () => {
      let avarage = 0
      const list: Array<any> = []
      const temp = ivdMetricsItems
      temp &&
        temp
          ?.sort((a, b) => a?.ivd - b?.ivd)
          .forEach((item, i) => {
            if (i <= 4) {
              list.push(item?.ivd.toFixed(2))
              avarage += item?.ivd
            }
          })
      const avarageValue = avarage / list?.length
      return {
        list: list,
        avarage: parseFloat(avarageValue.toFixed(2)),
      }
    }

    function mean(arr: any, n: number) {
      let sum = 0
      for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) sum += arr[i]
      return sum / n
    }

    function meanDeviation(arr: any, n: number) {
      let absSum = 0
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-plusplus
      for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) absSum += Math.abs(arr[i] - mean(arr, n))
      return absSum / n
    }

    function meanDeviationValue() {
      const list: Array<number> = []
      ivdMetricsItems.forEach(item => {
        if (item?.ivd) list.push(item?.ivd)
      })
      const deviationValue = meanDeviation(list, list.length)
      if (deviationValue) return deviationValue.toFixed(2)
      return '-'
    }

    function coefficientVariation() {
      const avarage =
        ivdMetricsItems.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.ivd, 0) /
        ivdMetricsItems.length
      const deviation = deviationValue()
      if (avarage && deviation) {
        const coefficient = (deviation / avarage) * 100
        return coefficient.toFixed(2)
      }
      return '-'
    }

    function ideals() {
      const list = ivdMetricsItems.filter(
        item => item?.ivd >= ivdMetrics?.desirableIvd
      )
      const percentage = (
        (list?.length / ivdMetricsItems?.length) *
        100
      ).toFixed(2)

      return {
        number: list?.length,
        percentage: percentage,
      }
    }

    function intervalValue() {
      if (ivdMetrics.measurementDate && rastreability?.startDate) {
        const a = moment(ivdMetrics?.measurementDate).tz('America/Sao_Paulo')
        const b = moment(rastreability?.startDate).tz('America/Sao_Paulo')
        const days = a.diff(b, 'days')
        return days
      }
      return 'Não informado'
    }

    let ivdMetricsSamples = []

    if (ivdMetricsItems?.length) {
      ivdMetricsItems?.forEach((item, index) => {
        if (!item.exclude) {
          ivdMetricsSamples.push({
            sample: index + 1,
            bulbSize: item.budSize.toFixed(2),
            toothSize: item.cloveSize.toFixed(2),
            ivd: item.ivd.toFixed(2),
            desirableIvd: ivdMetrics?.desirableIvd,
            ivdVariation: item.variation.toFixed(2),
          })
        }
      })
    }

    const planningDaysMultiple = (
      _start: any,
      _end?: any,
      measurementDate?: any
    ) => {
      const start = moment(_start)
      const end = moment(_end)
      const msDate = moment(measurementDate)
      if (_end) {
        if (msDate > end) {
          const duration = moment.duration(end.diff(start))
          const _days = duration.asDays()
          return { days: Math.round(_days), label: 'Dias em' }
        }
        if (msDate >= start && msDate <= end) {
          const duration = moment.duration(msDate.diff(start))
          const _days = duration.asDays()
          return { days: Math.round(_days), label: 'Dias em' }
        }
        if (msDate < start) {
          const duration = moment.duration(start.diff(msDate))
          const _days = duration.asDays()
          return { days: Math.round(_days), label: 'Dias para' }
        }
      }
      if (!_end) {
        if (msDate < start) {
          const duration = moment.duration(start.diff(msDate))
          const _days = duration.asDays()
          return { days: Math.round(_days), label: 'Dias para o plantio' }
        }
      }
      return { days: 0, label: 'Dias para o plantio' }
    }

    let planningSteps = []

    if (ivdMetrics?.lotId?.plannings?.length) {
      ivdMetrics?.lotId?.plannings?.forEach(item => {
        const pDays = !isSingle
          ? planningDaysMultiple(item?.startDate, item?.endDate)
          : planningDaysMultiple(
            item?.startDate,
            item?.endDate,
            ivdMetrics?.measurementDate
          )
        planningSteps.push({
          step: item?.stepId?.description.toUpperCase(),
          start: moment(item?.startDate)
            .tz('America/Sao_Paulo')
            .format('DD/MM/YY'),
          end: moment(item?.endDate).tz('America/Sao_Paulo').format('DD/MM/YY'),
          daysFixed: this.planningDaysFixed(item?.startDate, item?.endDate),
          days: pDays?.days,
          label: `${pDays?.label} ${item?.stepId?.description}`,
        })
      })
    }

    const infoPlantingDestiny = {
      date: moment(ivdMetrics?.destinyPlantingId?.plantingDate)
        .tz('America/Sao_Paulo')
        .format('DD/MM/YY'),
      days: planningDaysMultiple(
        ivdMetrics?.destinyPlantingId?.plantingDate,
        null,
        isSingle ? ivdMetrics?.measurementDate : new Date()
      ).days,
      label: planningDaysMultiple(ivdMetrics?.destinyPlantingId?.plantingDate)
        .label,
    }

    const formattedIvdMetrics = {
      lot: ivdMetrics?.lotId?.description.toUpperCase() || 'Não informado',
      productName:
        ivdMetrics?.lotId?.productId?.description.toUpperCase() ||
        'Não informado',
      originPlanting:
        `${ivdMetrics?.originPlantingId?.description.toUpperCase()}:
        ${moment(ivdMetrics?.originPlantingId?.plantingDate)
          .tz('America/Sao_Paulo')
          .format('DD/MM/YY')}
        - ${moment(ivdMetrics?.originPlantingId?.harvestDate)
          .tz('America/Sao_Paulo')
          .format('DD/MM/YY')}` || 'Não informado',
      destinationPlanting:
        `${ivdMetrics?.destinyPlantingId?.description.toUpperCase()}:
         ${moment(ivdMetrics?.destinyPlantingId?.plantingDate)
          .tz('America/Sao_Paulo')
          .format('DD/MM/YY')}
         - ${moment(ivdMetrics?.destinyPlantingId?.harvestDate)
          .tz('America/Sao_Paulo')
          .format('DD/MM/YY')}` || 'Não informado',
      infoPlantingDestiny: infoPlantingDestiny,
      variety: ivdMetrics?.lotId?.variety || 'Não informado',
      generation: ivdMetrics?.lotId?.generation || 'Não informado',
      classification:
        `${ivdMetrics?.plantingClassifiedId?.classId?.description} / ${ivdMetrics?.plantingClassifiedId?.unityId?.description} ${ivdMetrics?.plantingClassifiedId?.quantity}` ||
        'Não informado',
      releaseDate:
        moment(ivdMetrics?.measurementDate)
          .tz('America/Sao_Paulo')
          .format('DD/MM/YY') || 'Não informado',
      measurementDate:
        moment(ivdMetrics?.measurementDate)
          .tz('America/Sao_Paulo')
          .format('DD/MM/YY HH:mm') || 'Não informado',
      situation: ivdMetrics?.stepId?.description || 'Não informado',
      rastreability: {
        startDate: rastreability
          ? moment(rastreability?.startDate)
            .tz('America/Sao_Paulo')
            .format('DD/MM/YY HH:mm')
          : 'Não informado',
        interval: intervalValue(),
      },
      user: ivdMetrics?.createdBy?.username || '-',
      observation: ivdMetrics?.observation || '-',
      samples: ivdMetricsSamples,
      planningSteps: planningSteps,
      deviationValue: deviationValue(),
      deviationVariationValue: deviationVariationValue(),
      bulbSizeAverage: (
        ivdMetricsItems.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.budSize, 0) /
        ivdMetricsItems.length
      ).toFixed(2),
      toothSizeAverage: (
        ivdMetricsItems.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.cloveSize, 0) /
        ivdMetricsItems.length
      ).toFixed(2),
      ivdAvarage: (
        ivdMetricsItems.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.ivd, 0) /
        ivdMetricsItems.length
      ).toFixed(2),
      desirableIvdAvarage: ivdMetrics?.desirableIvd,
      ivdVariationAverage: (
        ivdMetricsItems.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.variation, 0) /
        ivdMetricsItems.length
      ).toFixed(2),
      highestAverages: higherAverages()?.list,
      lowerAverages: minorsAverages()?.list,
      higherAverage: higherAverages()?.avarage,
      lowerAverage: minorsAverages()?.avarage,
      average10Extremes: (
        (higherAverages()?.avarage + minorsAverages()?.avarage) /
        2
      ).toFixed(2),
      meanDeviation: meanDeviationValue(),
      coefficientVariation: coefficientVariation(),
      ideals: ideals(),
    }

    await qr.release()
    return formattedIvdMetrics
  }
```

The timeout for the instance is 180000.